# Arduino mega project (25 LEDS). How do I use a button to cycle through 3 different functions?

Tags: button, arduino, led, arduino-c++

I'm trying to cycle through 3 functions with a button. I have an arduino mega, 25 LED's and a tactile switch. This is the code I have now but it doesn't do anything.

```
    //initializing LEDS

#define PIN_COUNT    25
int pins[] = {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26};
#define BUTTON_PIN   27

// Variables will change:
int buttonPushCounter = 0;   // counter for the number of button presses
int buttonState = 0;         // current state of the button
int lastButtonState = 0;     // previous state of the button

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  for (int i=0; i<PIN_COUNT; i++){    
   pinMode(pins[i], OUTPUT);            
  }
pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() {
// read the pushbutton input pin:
 buttonState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);

 // compare the buttonState to its previous state
 if (buttonState != lastButtonState) {
   // if the state has changed, increment the counter
   if (buttonState == HIGH) {
     // if the current state is HIGH then the button went from off to on:
     buttonPushCounter++;
     Serial.println("on");
     Serial.print("number of button pushes: ");
     Serial.println(buttonPushCounter);
   } else {
     // if the current state is LOW then the button went from on to off:
     Serial.println("off");
   }
   // Delay a little bit to avoid bouncing
   delay(50);
 }
 // save the current state as the last state, for next time through the loop
 lastButtonState = buttonState;


 // turns on the LED every four button pushes by checking the modulo of the
 // button push counter. 
   if (buttonPushCounter == 0) {
     //turn everything off
   }
     if (buttonPushCounter == 1) {
       for(int i=0; i<=24; i++){
        digitalWrite(pins[i], HIGH);
       }
     }
     else if (buttonPushCounter == 2) {
       for(int i=0; i<=24; i++){
        digitalWrite(pins[i], HIGH);
        delay(100);
       }
     }
     else if (buttonPushCounter == 3) {
       for (int i=0; i<PIN_COUNT; i++){    // chasing right
          digitalWrite(pins[i], HIGH);         // switching the LED at index i on
          delay(100);                          // stopping the program for 100 milliseconds
          digitalWrite(pins[i], LOW);          // switching the LED at index i off
        }
        for (int i=PIN_COUNT-1; i>0; i--){   // chasing left (except the outer leds)
          digitalWrite(pins[i], HIGH);         // switching the LED at index i on
          delay(100);                          // stopping the program for 100 milliseconds
          digitalWrite(pins[i], LOW);          // switching the LED at index i off
        }
       buttonPushCounter = 0;
        }
     else {
       buttonPushCounter = 0;
     }
   }



void chaser(){
  for (int i=0; i<PIN_COUNT; i++){    // chasing right
    digitalWrite(pins[i], HIGH);         // switching the LED at index i on
    delay(100);                          // stopping the program for 100 milliseconds
    digitalWrite(pins[i], LOW);          // switching the LED at index i off
  }
  for (int i=PIN_COUNT-1; i>0; i--){   // chasing left (except the outer leds)
    digitalWrite(pins[i], HIGH);         // switching the LED at index i on
    delay(100);                          // stopping the program for 100 milliseconds
    digitalWrite(pins[i], LOW);          // switching the LED at index i off
  }
}

void oneByOne(){
  for(int i=0; i<=24; i++){
  digitalWrite(pins[i], HIGH);
  delay(100);
  }
}

void allOn(){
  for(int i=0; i<=24; i++){
  digitalWrite(pins[i], HIGH);
  }
}
```

On the bottom I've also written the 3 functions but they're now in the if statement cause I thought that might help. Also does the button need a resistor? Because I'm using the same kind of button for a different arduino project with an arduino Uno and 2 neopixel rings and the button there doesn't need a resistor.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, nice way to set the pin modes! There is nothing happening, because youre first if clause is never opened, because the button state is either high or low, therefore you cant use it like that. You could save the last buttonstate by setting lastbuttonstate = Buttonstate after each pass, to listen for changes. Then it would probably work. Also, for that to work you would need to set the last buttonstate before hand once to HIGH or LOW.

Greetings from Germany

Comment: Thanks for the responds! I actually did make it work with a view tweaks but I appreciate it.